# I am required to structure the C# coding better by organizing code into functions. I am not sure how to go about this:

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, refactoring

I am using the VideoGames Database (SQL) and i am coding an ASP Project (VISUAL STUDIO).
The page has coding which is not organised properly and certain functionality is called by repeating coding. I am required to structure the C# coding better by organizing code into functions. Can someone please give me a guideline on how to go about it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ASPLinqToSql
{
    public partial class About : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ctx = new VideoGamesDataContext();
            var products = from p in ctx.Products
                           select new
                           {
                               p.ProductID,
                               p.ProductName,
                               p.ProductDescription,
                               p.ListPrice
                           };
            GridView1.DataSource = products;
            GridView1.DataBind(); 
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int SupplierID = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            var ctx = new VideoGamesDataContext();
            var products = from p in ctx.Products
                           where p.SupplierID == SupplierID
                           select new
                           {
                               p.ProductID,
                               p.ProductName,
                               p.ProductDescription,
                               p.ListPrice
                           };
            GridView1.DataSource = products;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkLike.Checked == true)
            {
                int Supplierid = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                var ctx = new VideoGamesDataContext();
                var products = from p in ctx.Products
                               where p.SupplierID == Supplierid
                               && p.ProductName.StartsWith(txtProductName.Text.ToString())
                               select new
                               {
                                   p.ProductID,
                                   p.ProductName,
                                   p.ProductDescription,
                                   p.ListPrice
                               };
                GridView1.DataSource = products;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                int Supplierid = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                var ctx = new VideoGamesDataContext();
                var products = from p in ctx.Products
                               where p.SupplierID == Supplierid
                               select new
                               {
                                   p.ProductID,
                                   p.ProductName,
                                   p.ProductDescription,
                                   p.ListPrice
                               };
                GridView1.DataSource = products;
                GridView1.DataBind(); 

            }
        }
```

Comment: Such a broad topic, but every linq you have there is just repeated code, just move the code into one method and call that method multiple times

Comment: What @Sayse said, with `SupplierID` and `ProductName` as optional parameters (and subsequently optional filter arguments). Also, I suppose you have a checkbox (`chkLike`) to toggle between filtering by product name or not. From that I would assume a real LIKE filter (`Contains`) and not just a `StartsWith`. But that's just naming convention.

Comment: Thank you. I am just unsure about the query/statement that looks a bit different, for example: 'var products = from p in ctx.Products
                           where p.SupplierID == SupplierID
                           select new
                           {' ... it has a 'where'. should i implement an if/else statement in the method?

Comment: If anything I'd say make a more methods, try not to duplicate code where possible

Comment: @Sayse - but more methods with essentially the same body is what OP has now...

Comment: @Corak - His product searches are fundamentally different, although similar, I'd imagine a clearly typed method name will help explain this

Comment: @Sayse - the product search itself. agreed. So methods like `GetAllProducts()`, `GetProductsBySupplierID(int supplierID)` and `GetProductsBySupplierIDAndProductName(int supplierID, string productName)`.

Comment: Are we doing homework :-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start from separating UI logic (i.e. assigning data to controls and reading data from controls) from Data Access logic (i.e. making queries to database). I suggest you not only extract methods, but also extract classes:

Products repository, which hides all data access logic:

```
public interface IProductsRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> FindAll();
    IEnumerable<Product> FindBySupplierId(int supplierId);
}

public class ProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
{
    private object _propertyName;
    private DbContext _db;

    public ProductsRepository(DbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> FindAll()
    {
        return _db.Set<Product>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> FindBySupplierId(int supplierId)
    {
        return _db.Set<Product>()
                  .Where(p => p.SupplierID == supplierId);
    }
}
```

Also I'd create view model class instead of creating same anonymous objects each time:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }
}
```

And used [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map between Product and ProductViewModel. Place mapping configuration in Global.asax

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>();
```

Next - move products displaying into separate method. Now your code will look like:

```
public partial class About : Page
{
    private IProductsRepository _productsRepository;

    public About()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>();
        var db = new VideoGamesDataContext();
        _productsRepository = new ProductsRepository(db);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var products = _productsRepository.FindAll();
        ShowProducts(products);
    }

    void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int supplierID = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        var products = _productsRepository.FindBySupplierId(supplierID);
        ShowProducts(products);
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int supplierID = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        var products = _productsRepository.FindBySupplierId(supplierID);

        if(chkLike.Checked)
        {
            string name = txtProductName.Text;
            products = products.Where(p => p.ProductName.StartsWith(name));
        }

        ShowProducts(products);
    }

    public void ShowProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        var viewModels = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>>(products);
        GridView1.DataSource = viewModels;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Next steps - [injecting repository to page](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), or even extracting [Presenter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14642/Model-View-Presenter-with-ASP-NET), to keep UI very simple.

Comment: +1. It goes beyond of the scope of the question (simple method refactoring) to make him think about refactoring, design pattern and good practices in general.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code, one thing which comes to my mind that can be put into a function could be as below:

You can write a function to get list of products according to search criteria. e.g.

```
private List<Product> GetProducts(string SupplierId, string ProductName)
{
    //here you can pass SupplierId and ProductName as null when filtering 
    // is not required.
    var products = null;

     if(SupplierID != null)
     {
      products = from p in ctx.Products
                       select new
                       {
                           p.ProductID,
                           p.ProductName,
                           p.ProductDescription,
                           p.ListPrice
                       };
      }
     else
     {
         products = from p in ctx.Products
                       where p.SupplierID == SupplierID
                       select new
                       {
                           p.ProductID,
                           p.ProductName,
                           p.ProductDescription,
                           p.ListPrice
                       };
      }
}
```

Like this, you can put conditions and combine your query in one single function and call it whenever required.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have just moved the duplication elsewhere. This can be further refactored to remove the repetitive LINQ parts.

Comment: Hi Simon, I agree with you. But, this was just to give him an idea about separation. I understand it can be refactored futher. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To arrange your entire code, You need to separate it into layers. For this create a blank solution add Two class file project  and a web application or website. The two class library project should be DAL and BAL and UI will be your WebApp or Website project.

1. DAL
2. BAL
3. UI
4. DAL : It will be your dataaccess layer made up of Datacontext and some custom helper classes. you can opt for Repository pattern for the same. To Create a repository for CRUD operations for all tables. See these two articles
5. http://www.iainbenson.com/programming/C-Sharp/LanguageLearner/ORM.php
6. http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/linq2sql-and-repository-pattern
7. Now you can have a Business Layer where you have all your business logic/calculations or objects. In this project add the reference of your DAL project to access the DataObjects
8. Add the reference of the Business layer to Ui layer and acess the code accordingly.

Also you can create another Class library type of project for few common methods that can be accessed in entire solution. For example Sending Mail, Custom Parsing, String Operations and so on as per your project requirement.

[N- Layered Architecture](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/) :  also you can refer http://mikesdotnetting.com for additional resources..These two sites I found very useful to .net developers.